# How can I give full access to www-data to a folder in /var/www

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, php

I'm trying to give access to www-data which is a user created by apache.
I've tried to chmod 777 but that didn't worked. I want this access by default for all files in a specific directory, so that PHP can create, write and delete files or folders in that directory. Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I changed permission via Windows (sambashare) now it's working.